# CSS help | Menu

Tags: html, css

Please look at the site
http://dreamsnw.com/faiq123/

Problem is of jerking and menu are colliding with each other and also it is widely spread around the whole screen,i just want to squeeze down to center.Navs are collidng with each other.i have set position  parent to absolute and child to relative.Nothing working.

```
#menu-nav {
    width: 20em;
    padding: 0 0 0em 0;
    height:5em;
    margin-bottom: 5em;
    position:relative;


}
#menu-nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
    line-height:13px;
}
#menu-nav li{
    margin: -5px;
    list-style: none;
}
#menu-nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 5px 3px 0.25em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    line-height:13px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

html>body #menu-nav li a {
    width: auto;
}

#menu-nav li a:hover  {

}
#menu-nav #item1 a:hover
{  
background-image:url(images/navs/AboutUs.png);
line-height:40px;
background-position:left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight:bold;
position:absolute;
}
#menu-nav #item2 a:hover
{  
background-image:url(images/navs/AboutUs.png);
line-height:35px;
background-position:left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight:bold;
position:absolute;
}

#menu-nav #item3 a:hover
{  
background-image:url(images/navs/Services&product.png);
line-height:35px;
background-position:left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight:bold;
position:absolute;
}

#menu-nav #item4 a:hover
{  
background-image:url(images/navs/Potfolio.png);
line-height:35px;
background-position:left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight:bold;
position:absolute;
}
#menu-nav #item5 a:hover
{  
background-image:url(images/navs/Whyus.png);
line-height:35px;
background-position:left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight:bold;
position:absolute;
}
#menu-nav #item6 a:hover
{  
background-image:url(images/navs/CSR.png);
line-height:35px;
background-position:left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight:bold;
position:absolute;
}

#menu-nav #item7 a:hover
{  
background-image:url(images/navs/Contactus.png);
line-height:35px;
background-position:left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight:bold;
position:absolute;
}

#menu-nav #item8 a:hover
{  
background-image:url(images/navs/Careers.png);
line-height:35px;
background-position:left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight:bold;
position:absolute;
}


#menu-nav2 {
    width: 20em;
    padding: 0 0 0em 0;
    height:5em;
    margin-bottom: 5em;
    position:relative;
    }
#menu-nav2  ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
}
#menu-nav2  li{
    margin: -5px;
    list-style: none;
}
#menu-nav2  li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 5px 3px 0.25em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;

    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

html>body #menu-nav2  li a {
    width: auto;
}

#menu-nav2 li a:hover {

}


#menu-nav2 #item9 a:hover
{  
background-image:url(images/navs/SAPDevlopment.png);
line-height:35px;
background-position:left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight:bold;
position:absolute;
}
#menu-nav2 #item10 a:hover
{  
background-image:url(images/navs/SARemotebase.png);
line-height:35px;
background-position:left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight:bold;
position:absolute;
}
#menu-nav2 #item11 a:hover
{  
background-image:url(images/navs/SARemotebase.png);
line-height:35px;
background-position:left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight:bold;
position:absolute;
}
#menu-nav2 #item12 a:hover
{  
background-image:url(images/navs/Sapconstant.png);
line-height:35px;
background-position:left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight:bold;
position:absolute;
}

#menu-nav2 #item13 a:hover
{  
background-image:url(images/navs/Sapconstant.png);
line-height:35px;
background-position:left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight:bold;
position:absolute;
}

#menu-nav2 #item14 a:hover
{  
background-image:url(images/navs/SapABAP.png);
line-height:35px;
background-position:left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight:bold;
position:absolute;
}
#menu-nav2 #item15 a:hover
{  
background-image:url(images/navs/Appleiostraining.png);
line-height:35px;
background-position:left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight:bold;
position:absolute;
}

.main-menu-div
{
width: 100%;
padding: 5px; 
margin-left:60px;
}
.main-menu-content
{
margin-top:4px;
}
.main-menu-div-2
{
float: left;
width: 20%;
height:170px;
color:#FFFFFF;

}
.main-menu-div-3
{
float: left;
width: 16%;
height:170px;
border:#ffffff;
color:#FFFFFF;

}
.main-menu-div-4
{
float: left;
width: 22%;
height:170px;
border:#ffffff;
color:#FFFFFF;
}
.main-menu-div-5
{
float: left;
width: 22%;
height:170px;
color:#FFFFFF;
}

HTML
<div class="main-menu-div">
 <!-- main-menu-div starts -->
     <div class="main-menu-div-2"> 
     <div class="main-menu-content">
     <div id="menu-nav">
     <ul>
     <li id="item1">
     <div align="left"><a href="#"><div style="margin-left:70px;">Home</div></a></div>
     </li>

     <li id="item2">
     <div align="left"><a href="#"><div style="margin-left:70px;">About Us</div></a></div>
     </li>

     <li id="item3">
     <div align="left"><a href="#"><div style="margin-left:70px;">Services &amp; Products</div></a></div>
     </li>


     <li id="item4">
     <div align="left"><a href="#"><div style="margin-left:70px;">Portfolio</div></a></div>
     </li>
     </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>

     <div class="main-menu-div-3">
     <div class="main-menu-content">
     <div id="menu-nav">
     <ul>
     <li id="item5">
     <div align="left"><a href="#"><div style="margin-left:70px; ">Why Us</div></a></div>
     </li>

     <li id="item6">
     <div align="left"><a href="#"><div style="margin-left:70px;">CSR</div></a></div>
     </li>

     <li id="item7">
     <div align="left"><a href="#"><div style="margin-left:70px;">Contact Us</div></a></div>
     </li>

     <li id="item8">
     <div align="left"><a href="#"><div style="margin-left:70px;">Careers</div></a></div>
     </li>
     </ul>
     </div> 
     </div>
     </div>


     <div class="main-menu-div-4">
     <div class="main-menu-content">
     <div id="menu-nav2">
     <ul class="menu-nav ">
     <li id="item9">
     <div align="left"><a href="#"><div style="margin-left:70px; ">SAP Development</div></a></div>
     </li>

     <li id="item10">
     <div align="left"><a href="#"><div style="margin-left:70px;">SAP Remote Basis</div></a></div>
     </li>

     <li id="item11">
     <div align="left"><a href="#"><div style="margin-left:70px;">SAP Low Cost Support</div></a></div>
     </li>

     <li id="item12">
     <div align="left"><a href="#"><div style="margin-left:70px;">Contract SAP Consultants</div></a></div>
     </li>
     </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>

     <div class="main-menu-div-5">
     <div class="main-menu-content">
     <div id="menu-nav2">
     <ul>
     <li id="item13">
     <div align="left"><a href="#"><div style="margin-left:70px; ">Smartphone Development</div></a></div>
     </li>
     <li id="item14">
     <div align="left"><a href="#"><div style="margin-left:70px;">SAP ABAP Training</div></a></div>
     </li>
     <li id="item15">
     <div align="left"><a href="#"><div style="margin-left:70px;">Apple iOS Training</div></a></div>
     </li>    
     </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>

 <br style="clear: left;" />
 </div>
```

**Jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/JeJTs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hover over a link, it displays an image. You set this image using background-image. At the same time, you change the line-height of the link to the height of the image. This causes the link to get "shoved" down, overlapping the links below.

This is where your problem is. In order to display the image properly, you need need to set the height of the link element to the side of the image. But by applying `line-height` (or `height`), you will cause the link to either overlap its siblings, or otherwise shove the other links aside.

The best way to get the effect you want is to use a Javascript plugin like JQuery to do a custom tooltip (the image) and only apply the background-color on `:hover`.

Comment: here is the code,can you tell me where i put this thing you said  #menu-nav2 #item14 a:hover
{  
background-image:url(images/navs/SapABAP.png);
line-height:35px;
background-position:left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight:bold;
}

Comment: @FAIQNASEEM - You should use a [JavaScript plugin](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/) like JQuery. It is very difficult (and very messy) to do it in pure CSS. Infinitely more messy if you want it cross-browser.

Comment: any plugin you suggest??Name of it to create such type of thing

Comment: [Here is a tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/2294/useful-and-practical-jquery-image-tooltips-tutorial). Really, just google "jquery image tooltip" and you'll find many.

Comment: can image tooltip will work ???

Comment: ... Yes. Use a tooltip to get the image to display (using a plugin in JavaScript.) Then change your CSS to *only* do the background-color change when you hover over it with your mouse. Do not do the `background-image` in the CSS.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VejQu/ where to put image

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a div for each menu item, this is not a good practice, [here's](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/06/03/how-to-create-a-horizontal-dropdown-menu-with-html-css-and-jquery/) how to create a simple menu.